# Facing issues regarding my Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lookup field and whenever i am trying to enter a value and save it to database it isnt saving.When looked in the debug log it gives a DML exception: MalformedId,Id value of incorrect type.

can anyone please help me out on this.

Thanks

This is my Component:

```
<!--HANDLER-->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<!-- ATTRIBUTES-->
<aura:attribute name="rules" type="Rule__c[]" />
<aura:attribute name="newRule1" type="Rule__c" default="{'Rule_Set__c': ' ', 'Value__c': '', 'Object_API_Name__c': ' ',
                                                            'Field_API_Name':' ', Operator__c:'','sobjectType': 'Rule__c'}" />
<aura:attribute name="toggletxt" type="boolean" default="true" />
<aura:attribute name="toggleNum" type="boolean" />



<!--<aura:registerEvent name="navigate" type="c:addItemEvent"/> -->



 <lightning:layout class="slds-page-header slds-page-header--object-home">

    <lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:scan_card" alternativeText="Rule Modal"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
        <div class="page-section page-header">
            <h1 class="slds-text-heading--label">Rule</h1>
            <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">Rule Modal</h2>
        </div>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
<lightning:layout>

    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-medium" size="5">

        <!-- CREATE NEW Entry -->
        <div aria-labelledby="newRule1">

            <!-- BOXED AREA -->
            <fieldset class= "slds-box slds-theme--default slds-container--large">
                <legend id= "newRule1" class= "slds-text-heading--large 
                                                   slds-p-vertical--large">
                    RULE Modal Entry
                </legend>

                <!-- CREATE NEW RuleSet FORM -->
                <form class= "slds-form--stacked">          
                    <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="modalForm" label="Rule Set"
                                     name="modalRuleSet"
                                     value="{!v.newRule1.Rule_Set__c}"
                                     required="true"/> 

                    <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="modalForm" label="ObjectAPIName"
                                     name="modalObjectApiName"
                                     value="{!v.newRule1.Object_API_Name__c}" />

                    <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="modalForm" label="FieldAPIName"
                                     name="modalFieldApiName"
                                     value="{!v.newRule1.Field_API_Name__c}" />
                    <!--Picklist Values-->
                    <lightning:select aura:id="modalForm" name="modalOperator" 
                                            label="Operator" 
                                            onchange="{!c.handleChange}">
                            <option value="">All Types</option>
                            <option value="equals">Equals</option>
                            <option value="does not equals">Does Not Equals</option>
                            <option value="greater than">Greater Than</option>
                            <option value="less than">Less Than</option>
                            <option value="greater than equal too">Greater than Equal Too</option>
                            <option value="less than equal too">Less than Equal too</option>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.Types}" var="T">
                            <option text="{!T.Name}" value="{!T.Id}" ></option>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>
                    <!-- End Of Picklist Value-->

                    <!-- Start of Multiple If's-->

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.toggleTxt}">
    <div class="demo-only demo-only--sizing slds-grid slds-wrap slds-p-vertical_medium">
        <div class="slds-size_3-of-12 slds-p-left_xx-large slds-p-horizontal_x-large" >
            <lightning:input type="Text" label="Text" name="Text" value=" "/>
        </div>
    </div>      
    <aura:set attribute="else">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.toggleNum}">                   
        <div class="demo-only demo-only--sizing slds-grid slds-wrap slds-p-vertical_medium">
            <div  class="slds-size_3-of-12 slds-p-left_xx-large slds-p-horizontal_x-large">
                <lightning:input type="Number" label="Number" name="Number" value=" "/>
            </div>
        </div>              
        </aura:if>
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

```
                    <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="modalForm" label="Value"  
                                     name="modalValue"
                                     checked="{!v.newRule1.Value__c}"/>

                    <lightning:button label="Save" 
                                      class= "slds-m-top--medium"
                                      variant="brand"
                                      onclick="{!c.clickSave }"/>
                </form>
                <!-- / CREATE NEW Rule Form -->

            </fieldset>
            <!-- / BOXED AREA -->
        </div>
        <!-- / CREATE NEW Entry -->
    </lightning:layoutItem>

</lightning:layout>

<div class="slds-card slds-p-top--medium">

    <section class="slds-card__body">
        <div id="list" class="row">

            <aura:iteration items="{!v.rules}" var="objrule">
                <c:RuleModalList rule="{!objrule}"/>
            </aura:iteration>

        </div>
    </section>
</div>    

<!-- <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="basicinfoform" 
    recordId="{!v.newRule1}"  
    objectApiName="Rule__c">    
    <lightning:messages/>
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="Operator" fieldName="Operator__c" value=""/><br/>                    

</lightning:recordEditForm>-->
```

This is my controller:

({

```
clickSave : function(component, event, helper) {
    var isFormValid = component.find("modalForm").reduce(function(isValid, inputCmp){
        inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();        
        return isValid && inputCmp.get("v.validity").valid;
    });

    if (isFormValid) {

        var newRule = component.get("v.newRule1");
        helper.createRules(component,newRule);

    }
},

doInit : function (component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getRule");

    action.setCallback(this,function (response) { 
        var rule = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.rules",rule);

       // component.find("Operator").set("v.value", Approve);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},


handleChange: function (cmp, evt, helper) {
     var sel = component.find("modalForm");
     var nav =  sel.get("v.value");
     if (nav == "INDIA") {     
          component.set("v.toggleGer", true);
     }
     else if(nav == "USA"){
        component.set("v.toggleGer", false);
        component.set("v.toggleEng", false);
     }
 else if(nav == "GERMAN"){
        component.set("v.toggleGer", false);
        component.set("v.toggleEng", true);
     }
```

})

this is my helper:

({
    createRules : function(component,newRule) {
        var action = component.get("c.saveRule");
        action.setParams({
            "rule" : newRule
        });

```
    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var parsedRule = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newRule));

            console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parsedRule)), JSON.stringify(parsedRule));

            var objRules = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.rules")));
            objRules.push(parsedRule);
            component.set("v.rules",objRules);
            component.set("v.newRule1", {'Rule_Set__c':'', 'Object_API_Name': 0, 'Value__c': 0, 'Field_API_Name__c': 0, 'Name':'','Operator__c':'', 'sobjectType': 'Rule__c'})
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

Please dont consider the handleChange part in the component as i am working on it currently and changes are under process.

Comment: Hey Shaurya, could you please add some code to help us understand how you implemented this?

Comment: yes sure i have shared my code

Comment: please share apex code

Comment: i already shared